# Cannot dynamic_cast ... to type ... (target is not pointer or reference)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Вот здесь не получается использовать RTTI:

```
catch (Sales::bad_index & bad)
{
    Sales::bad_index * badptr = &bad; // базовый класс 
    LabeledSales::nbad_index * nbadptr; // производный класс от Sales::bad_index
    if (nbadptr = dynamic_cast<LabeledSales::nbad_index> (badptr)) // <--- HERE
    {
        cout << nbadptr->what();
        cout << "Company: " << nbadptr->label_val() << endl;
        cout << "bad index: " << nbadptr->bi_val() << endl;
    }
    else if (typeid (Sales::bad_index) == typeid (bad))
    {
        cout << bad.what();
        cout << "bad index: " << bad.bi_val() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //throw ... std::bad_typeid ...
    }
}
```

Ну и, собственно, недовольство g++:

> main.cpp:52:69: error: cannot
> dynamic_cast ‘badptr’ (of type ‘class
> Sales::bad_index*’) to type ‘class
> LabeledSales::nbad_index’ (target is
> not pointer or reference)

Comment: typeid и dynamic_cast имеют одинаковые требования к операндам, зачем мешать их в одну кучу? Достаточно dynamic_cast.

Comment: Спасибо, flammable. То есть, Вы имеет ввиду во втором условии хватило бы     else if (nbadptr == nullptr)      ?

Кстати, нашел ошибку, в первом условии нужно ведь к указателю приводить:
if (nbadptr = dynamic_cast<LabeledSales::nbad_index * > (badptr))